# ArcObjects 10.1 .NET Convert Point from WGS1984 to OSGB1936

Tags: arcobjects, c#, convert, .net, coordinate-system

Please can someone help me convert a point in WGS1984 to OSGB1936, I have followed all the documentation (or so i think...) and yet have not made any headway into this problem. This is my code :

```
Type factoryType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriGeometry.SpatialReferenceEnvironment");
System.Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(factoryType);
ISpatialReferenceFactory3 spacialReferenceFactory3 = obj as ISpatialReferenceFactory3;

// Create Transformation from WGS84 to OSGB86
IGeoTransformation geoTrans = spacialReferenceFactory3.CreateGeoTransformation((int)esriSRGeoTransformationType.esriSRGeoTransformation_OSGB1936_To_WGS1984Petrol) as IGeoTransformation;

ISpatialReference fromSpatialReference;
ISpatialReference toSpatialReference;
geoTrans.GetSpatialReferences(out fromSpatialReference, out toSpatialReference);

IGeometry5 geometry;
IPoint point = new PointClass();
point.PutCoords(51.465615, -3.159875);
geometry = point as IGeometry5;
geometry.SpatialReference = toSpatialReference;
geometry.ProjectEx(fromSpatialReference, esriTransformDirection.esriTransformForward, geoTrans, false, 0.0, 0.0);
point = new PointClass();
point = geometry as IPoint;
```

My point is being returned from the Geometry object as 51.46200954514034, -3.1549783406850165. I have tried using the reverse transformation as specified in `geometry.ProjectEx()`, and all i get is the same X and Y as the original point. I have also tried different combinations of reverse / forward and also swapping the `fromSpatialReference` and `toSpatialReference`.

Comment: Maybe your x & y are reversed?  This point is out in the Indian Ocean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This prints: `319524.804848596 174709.885049006`.

```
private static void TestProjection()
{
    Type factoryType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriGeometry.SpatialReferenceEnvironment"); 
    System.Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(factoryType); 
    var srf = obj as ISpatialReferenceFactory3;

    // Create Transformation from WGS84 to OSGB86
    var geoTrans = srf.CreateGeoTransformation((int)esriSRGeoTransformationType.esriSRGeoTransformation_OSGB1936_To_WGS1984Petrol) as IGeoTransformation;

    ISpatialReference fromSpatialReference;
    ISpatialReference toSpatialReference;
    geoTrans.GetSpatialReferences(out fromSpatialReference, out toSpatialReference);

    var wgs84GCS =  srf.CreateGeographicCoordinateSystem((int)esriSRGeoCSType.esriSRGeoCS_WGS1984);
    var bngPCS = srf.CreateProjectedCoordinateSystem((int)esriSRProjCSType.esriSRProjCS_BritishNationalGrid);
    if((wgs84GCS.FactoryCode != toSpatialReference.FactoryCode)
        || (bngPCS.GeographicCoordinateSystem.FactoryCode != fromSpatialReference.FactoryCode))
    {
        throw new Exception("invalid geotransformation");
    }

    IGeometry5 geometry;
    IPoint point = new PointClass();
    point.PutCoords(-3.159875, 51.465615);
    geometry = point as IGeometry5;
    geometry.SpatialReference =wgs84GCS;

    geometry.ProjectEx(bngPCS, esriTransformDirection.esriTransformReverse, geoTrans, false, 0.0, 0.0);
    point = geometry as IPoint;
    Debug.Print("{0} {1}", point.X, point.Y);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to look at this Kirk, i am getting the values you mentioned - but my GIS specialist said that the point should convert to 319525, 174710. We want British National Grid Coords and he thought OSGB1936 Petrol would have converted to what we needed, this assumption was obviously incorrect. 

You don't happen to know how we could convert to British Nation Coordinates?

Comment: I've updated my answer to do this.

Comment: @leinad13 also, note that I flipped x & y.